# SQL Integer Range When Creating Tables

Tags: mysql, integer, range

I'm trying to give my INT in one of my create statements a range of possible values, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Site(
    **SiteID INT (1,4),**
    UserID INT UNSIGNED Not Null,
    Name varchar(128) Unique Not Null,
    Foreign Key (UserID) References Users(UserID),
    Primary key (SiteID)
);
```

I forget the syntax that you use for ranges, and I'm pretty sure I'm erring when I'm attempting to use it as is.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Comment: If it's your primary key, why do you want a range?

Comment: SiteID in this case refers to the authority level someone in the Site has, where 1 = Admin, 2 = second most power, 3 = 3rd most power, 4 = 4th most power.

Comment: That's what foreign keys are for.

Comment: So this table will only have 4 total records?  If you are limiting SiteID to between 1 and 4, and SiteID is your Primary Key, then this table can have a maximum of 4 records.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Author's Note**: the first two parts of this answer are incorrect. I thought MySQL supported `CHECK` constraints and it didn't. Still doesn't. To limit columns to a simple list of values, use the `ENUM` approach at the end of this answer. If the logic is more complicated (range of values, value based on another column, etc.), the only MySQL option is a trigger.

---

You need a `CHECK` constraint if it's an `INT`:

```
CREATE TABLE Site (
  SiteID INT,
  CONSTRAINT SiteID_Ck CHECK (SiteID IN (1, 2, 3, 4)),
  ... and the rest
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE Site (
  SiteID INT,
  CONSTRAINT SiteID_Ck CHECK (SiteID BETWEEN 1 AND 4),
  ... and the rest
```

Or if you can live with a string SiteID then:

```
CREATE TABLE Site (
  SiteID ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4'),
  ... and the rest
```

Comment: It looks like CHECK doesn't actually work in MySQL: "CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: You're right Jack, and thanks for pointing this out. I don't recall answering this question because it's been so long, but around that time I was just dabbling in MySQL after years of Oracle and SQL Server. I found out later that it didn't support CHECK constraints. Found it hard to believe, but 2+ years on it still doesn't. Curious, because I'd think it would be easier to implement than PK or FK. Still, the last option (the `ENUM`) works. I've added a disclaimer.